# PHP storm instant shortcut for ignoring auto-complete tags

Tags: phpstorm

Generally when we type a tag's name in PHPStorm it completes the closing tags for us.

If we type `<div` as soon as we press `>` it will append a `</div>` to the the `<div>`.

Is there any shortcut for us to make PHPStorm to not to do this and leave our type just as-is. I know there is an option in settings, but I don't want to deactivate it all, I need to deactivate it only on the fly at some instances...

Comment: There is no such shortcut simply because this behaviour is controlled by separate option (which you know about already).

Comment: What you *possibly* could do .. is to record a macro where you complete such tag in away that it does not trigger inserting closing tag (for example: by typing and then deleting some extra characters) and use that macro instead in such special cases. Not 100% sure that it is possible to do .. but at least worth exploring this idea.

Comment: thanks...I should consider writing some plugins for it :) :D